# Не выводится виджет Quick Chat

Tags: wordpress, плагин, чат, виджет

Помогите пожалуйста разобраться. Я пытаюсь вывести виджет Quick Chat в записи посредством шорткода сгенерированным плагином Shortcode Any Widget. В итоге выводится только "LOADING...
Работает на Quick Chat". Гугл говорит что Quick Chat не с каждой темой работает, однако решений этой проблемы не предлагает. Может кто имеет какие соображения на этот счет. Либо присоветуйте какой-нибудь аналог.

Answer (score 0):

Quich Chat имеет [плагин для WordPress](https://quickchat.pro/ru/kb/help/how-to-install-ok-wordpress). Попробуйте установить его.

Из альтернатив - использовал [Pozvonim](https://pozvonim.com/), [Jivosite](https://www.jivosite.ru/), [Cleversite](http://cleversite.ru/). Все работает. Наиболее удобным показался последний из трех упомянутых.